# Converting ext.getCmp to up() or down() in ExtJS 6 not returning anything

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have recently read that using `Ext.getCmp` is considered not very good, so I'm going around my app converting them to the recommended up() or down() method.

I have come up again a little problem though. In my login controller it doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why. My original controller with the `Ext.getCmp` is something like the following;

```
onLoginClick: function() {

    let formValues = this.getView().down('form').getValues();

    Application.login(formValues.email, formValues.password).then(function() {

        this.getView().destroy();

    }.bind(this), function(data) {
        Ext.getCmp('loginissues').setValue(data.message).show();
    });

}
```

and my view is a little like so;

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    id: 'loginissues',
    hidden: true
}, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    id: 'email',
    name: 'email',
    fieldLabel: 'Email',
    allowBlank: true
}, {
    name: 'password',
    inputType: 'password',
    fieldLabel: 'Password',
    allowBlank: true
}]
```

So basically what is happening is that if a failure is returned from the API, it loads the message into the displayfield and then unhides it. This all works perfect but if I change the id in the view to a `itemId` and then change the Ext.getCmp call to something like the following, it doesn't do anything at all.

```
this.getView().down('#loginissues').setValue(data.message).show();
```

no errors or anything.

Comment: Don't know where you got the idea that up/down are good replacements. Use the `reference` config on the component and `lookup` on the controller. There are examples in the documentation.

Comment: I was just reading it from here https://www.swarmonline.com/20-tips-for-getting-started-with-ext-js/ ... I'll have a look into the lookup, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break down with only this part of code :

```
this.getView().down('#loginissues')
```

Check console if you are able to get the reference successfully. Else change "down" to "up" function.

You can also try :

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#loginissues')
```

Although this method searches whole DOM, but it is immune to changes in view layout.
Place of the element in DOM matters, Element where control resided at point where you do "up" was below. So "up" works. If it(#loginissues) was below the control then "down" will work.
This("up" and "down" functions) is computation optimized search in DOM. Search will happen only for half part, so we'll catch reference faster than component query.

Comment: Hmm strange, neither of these work .. would it have anything to do with the bind(this) above the getCmp line?

Comment: "this.getView().destroy();" is executed. This will destroy DOM element you are trying to find. Hence, you are not able to find I think.

Comment: Thats only if the login is successful

Comment: change "id" to "itemId" , var 
 login  = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#loginissues')[0]. This should most probably work. Check if variable "login" is undefined or holds value to the reference.

Comment: That seemed to work ... I wonder why the down() didnt work though.... Thanks for your help

Comment: Place of the element in DOM matters, Element where control resided at point where you do "up" was below. So "up" works. If it(#loginissues) was below the control then "down" will work. This is computation optimized search in DOM will happen only for half part, so we'll catch reference faster than component query.